# Creating an animation on model in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

i have a 3D model(a cartoon character) and i want to animate this character in unity. For example i want to move its arms. I think i must start with determining the reference points but i dont know how to do this. Can anybody help to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I agree that it's much more desirable to fully construct the animations in dedicated software like Maya and Max, you can still perform very basic transform/etc. operations on character bones in order to get them to move.

At the base of the model heirachy, you have a gameObject with a Skinned Mesh Renderer attached. This essentially renders the model and any materials assigned to it, also allowing you to assign a 'root bone' for animation (in this example, Bip001). Each bone is just an empty gameObject with different set of **local** transform (position, rotation, scale) settings.

Since they're just nested gameObjects, you can attach or modify them with scripts that control their [transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html).

Essentially you can modify some basic movement into an existing bone heirarchy, but it really can't be recommended for fully animating models.

[image: Just a shot of the Unity premade character model, with bone structure]

At the bottom here i've selected wrench, which is separate to the character, but placed as a child of the Bip001 R Hand gameObject, forcing this model to move and rotate with the hand parent.

Comment: It might be really late to ask, but I am looking for this exact character model. Is there somewhere I can download it? Thanks

Comment: @JuZDePeche The model came as part of an official unitypackage named 'Character Controller' which was an optional part of the installation, at least it was back in the day. You may be able to find it either on the Unity Asset store, or by digging through Unity3D's older downloads section (vers 3.5 - 4.0) and look under additional resources that shipped with those releases.

Answer (score 2):

Its very hard to animate it in unity, I recommend you to animate it in Maya, the 3D model is rigged ? If not, you need to make the rigging. The rigging is that reference point. Unity is only a Game Engine, do the animation on Autodesk Maya, then export to .FBX and finally import to unity.

You can get information about character rigging in [this site](http://www.amazzing.com/tutoriais.htm) and go to the rigging tutorial.

You can play the animations using `Animation.Play("animationNameHere);`

Comment: Worth noting that Unity3d v4 has added some fancy new animation stuff, though I've not looked at it properly yet.

Comment: Unity 3.5.4 have some paid plugins that help in animations, I preffer to make on Maya, have more functions, the new animations of Unity is like the "ToonBoom" animating style. But is importante you increse this point =) +1 for you because I forgot this =P